# How can I validate a date string without rescuing the exception to keep the Rubocop HandleExceptions linter happy?

Tags: ruby, date, rubocop

I have a string which might or might not be a valid date.

I want a clean and simple way to validate whilst keeping Rubocop happy.

```
# TODO: Welcome suggestions for a better way to deal with this...
# rubocop:disable HandleExceptions
def self.valid_date?(date)
  Date.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
end
# rubocop:enable HandleExceptions
```

I actually feel like this is a clean way to achieve what I need, but is there a way to resolve whilst still keeping rubocop happy?

Answer (score 3):

Add a explicit `nil`:

```
# TODO: Welcome suggestions for a better way to deal with this...
# rubocop:disable HandleExceptions
def self.valid_date?(date)
  Date.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
  nil
end
```

Otherwise, enable inline `rescue` in `.rubocop.yml` for a shorter method:

```
Style/RescueModifier:
  Enabled: false
```

Then:

```
# TODO: Welcome suggestions for a better way to deal with this...
# rubocop:disable HandleExceptions
def self.valid_date?(date)
  Date.parse(date) rescue nil
end
```

Remember, how readable is your code does not deppend on what a machine says, but what other people (i.e. a community) feel about it. Rubocop is just a tool for a quick way to review code without reading line by line manually.

Comment: It seems there's no way other than disabling Rubocop in this instance - the RescueModifier is a lesser cop to disable so that feels better thanks. I do understand what the tool is there for, I was just hoping there might be a nice way to parse a date without having an exception thrown at me. I'll give you the accepted for providing a thoughtful response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
# rubocop:disable Style/RescueModifier
def self.valid_date?(date)
  Date.parse(date) rescue nil
end
# rubocop:enable Style/RescueModifier
```